# Jade template engine: show and hide a certain block

Tags: html, pug, template-engine

I have a jade template

```
extends _base
block content
  include ./partials/_main-header
  .Template2RightBig
    .container
      .row
        block content2RightBig
          .col-md-3.Template2RightBig--left.column
            block left-column
          .col-md-9.Template2RightBig--right.column
            .Template2RightBig--right-header
              block right-column-header
            .Template2RightBig--right-annotation
              block right-column-annotation
            block right-column
  include ./partials/_footer
```

I want to show or hide right-column-annotation block WITH its parent container(.Template2RightBig--right-annotation) in pages, which will extend this page.

How can I do that with Jade power?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a variable from your child page into this template through a new block in order to conditionally control anything in this template.

**_your-template.jade**

```
extends _base
block content
  include ./partials/_main-header
  .Template2RightBig
    .container
      .row
        block content2RightBig
          block page-variables
          .col-md-3.Template2RightBig--left.column
            block left-column
          .col-md-9.Template2RightBig--right.column
            .Template2RightBig--right-header
              block right-column-header
            if rightAnnotationVisible === true
              .Template2RightBig--right-annotation
                block right-column-annotation
            block right-column
  include ./partials/_footer
```

**_your-page.jade**

```
extends _your-template

block page-variables
  - var rightAnnotationVisible = true
  //- annotation and parent wrapper will render
```

**_your-other-page.jade**

```
extends _your-template

block page-variables
  - var rightAnnotationVisible = false
  //- annotation and parent wrapper won't render
```

Just be sure the new block is scoped to be included in the right place in the parent blocks.

Comment: Worked for me.   I would just add that for a newbie, "block is scoped...." means putting "block page-variables" in the _base template - in mine it is just follows . "doctype html"